# mysqli_fetch_array not updating

Tags: php, database, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have created a CMS system where you can create pages with a template system. Very simple and it works. I have a script on the admin interface that makes a list of all the created pages (at the same time that they link to the respective edit page), but the script is not working correctly: It shows the pages I created by manual insertion of data in the PHPmyadmin but not the ones that I created via CMS system.

I've already checked the database and the pages I created using my CMS system are there. Anyone can spot the mistake? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    require_once "../scripts/conector.php";

    if (!$_GET['pid']) {
    $pageid = '1';
    } else {
        $pageid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
    }

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, producent FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($myConnection)); 

    $producentnamn = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $producent = $row["producent"];
        $producentnamn .= '<a href="edit_page.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $producent . '</a>';
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
?>

<ul class="f-dropdown" id="drop1">
   <li><?php echo $producentnamn; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try print_r($row) in while what you get

Comment: is the showing is 1 on the insert, and the id are not 0?

Comment: The way you have it structured here you will put every link into a single 'li' pair. Not the error you speak of but still going to be a problem.

Comment: @user3052629 well spotted! It was 0. In the database I had it as Enum with '0','1' values but with no default. Problem solved! Truly thankful!

Comment: @ethrbunny why is it a problem? It is working as I want...

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

Comment: you'r welcome, i had those problems before so i know the feeling, make sure to check those things first when you are using mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake here, that outside while your trying to fetch var's value, so you have to save it in one array, like this

```
$arr=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $producent = $row["producent"];
        $producentnamn .= '<a href="edit_page.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $producent . '</a>';
       $arr[]=$producentnamn;
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
```

now try to fetch this,

```
print_r($arr);
```